# How do I run an object's method onEvent in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, events, methods, pointers

I just started using javascript and I'm missing something important in my knowledge.  I was hoping you could help me fill in the gap.

So the script I'm trying to run is suppose to count the characters in a text field, and update a paragraph to tell the user how many characters they have typed.  I have an object called charCounter.  sourceId is the id of the text area to count characters in.  statusId is the id of the paragraph to update everytime a key is pressed.

```
function charCounter(sourceId, statusId) {
    this.sourceId = sourceId;
    this.statusId = statusId;
    this.count = 0;
}
```

There is one method called updateAll.  It updates the count of characters and updates the paragraph.

```
charCounter.prototype.updateAll = function() {
    //get the character count;
    //change the paragraph;
}
```

I have a start function that is called when the window loads.

```
function start() {
    //This is the problem
    document.getElementbyId('mytextfield').onkeydown = myCounter.updateAll;
    document.getElementbyId('mytextfield').onkeyup = myCounter.updateAll;
}

myCounter = new charCounter("mytextfield","charcount");
window.onload = start;
```

The above code is the problem.  Why in the world can't I call the myCounter.updateAll method when the event is fired?  This is really confusing to me.  I understand that if you call a method **likeThis()** you'll get a value from the function.  If you call it **likeThis** you are getting a pointer to a function.  I'm pointing my event to a function.  I've also tried calling the function straight up and it works just fine, but it will not work when the event is fired.

What am I missing?

---

Thanks for all the answers.  Here's three different implementations.

## Implementation 1

```
function CharCounter(sourceId, statusId) {
    this.sourceId = sourceId;
    this.statusId = statusId;
    this.count = 0;
};
    CharCounter.prototype.updateAll = function() {
        this.count = document.getElementById(this.sourceId).value.length;
        document.getElementById(this.statusId).innerHTML = "There are "+this.count+" charactors";
    };

function start() {
    myCharCounter.updateAll();
    document.getElementById('mytextfield').onkeyup = function() { myCharCounter.updateAll(); };
    document.getElementById('mytextfield').onkeydown = function() { myCharCounter.updateAll(); };   
};

myCharCounter = new CharCounter('mytextfield','charcount');
window.onload = start;
```

## Implementation 2

```
function CharCounter(sourceId, statusId) {
    this.sourceId = sourceId;
    this.statusId = statusId;
    this.count = 0;
};
    CharCounter.prototype.updateAll = function() {
        this.count = document.getElementById(this.sourceId).value.length;
        document.getElementById(this.statusId).innerHTML = "There are "+ this.count+" charactors";
    };
    CharCounter.prototype.start = function() {
        var instance = this;
        instance.updateAll();

        document.getElementById(this.sourceId).onkeyup = function() {
            instance.updateAll();
        };
        document.getElementById(this.sourceId).onkeydown = function() {
            instance.updateAll();
        };
    };

window.onload = function() {
    var myCounter = new CharCounter("mytextfield","charcount");
    myCounter.start();
};
```

## Implementation 3

```
function CharCounter(sourceId, statusId) {
    this.sourceId = sourceId;
    this.statusId = statusId;
    this.count = 0;
};
    CharCounter.prototype.updateAll = function() {
        this.count = document.getElementById(this.sourceId).value.length;
        document.getElementById(this.statusId).innerHTML = "There are "+this.count+" charactors";
    };

function bind(funcToCall, desiredThisValue) {
    return function() { funcToCall.apply(desiredThisValue); };
};  

function start() {
    myCharCounter.updateAll();
    document.getElementById('mytextfield').onkeyup = bind(myCharCounter.updateAll,    myCharCounter);
    document.getElementById('mytextfield').onkeydown = bind(myCharCounter.updateAll, myCharCounter);
};

myCharCounter = new CharCounter('mytextfield','charcount');
window.onload = start;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are having problems accessing your instance members on the `updateAll` function, since you are using it as an event handler, the context (the `this` keyword) is the DOM element that triggered the event, not your CharCounter object instance.

You could do something like this:

```
function CharCounter(sourceId, statusId) {
    this.sourceId = sourceId;
    this.statusId = statusId;
    this.count = 0;
}

CharCounter.prototype.updateAll = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById(this.sourceId).value;
  document.getElementById(this.statusId).innerHTML = text.length;
};

CharCounter.prototype.start = function() {
  // event binding
  var instance = this; // store the current context
  document.getElementById(this.sourceId).onkeyup = function () {
    instance.updateAll(); // use 'instance' because in event handlers
                          // the 'this' keyword refers to the DOM element.
  }; 
}

window.onload = function () {
  var myCharCounter = new CharCounter('textarea1', 'status');
  myCharCounter.start();
};
```

Check the above example running [here](http://jsbin.com/oguhi).

Comment: Thank you!  That sheds a lot of light on my problem!

Answer (score 2):

The expression "myCounter.updateAll" merely returns a reference to the function object bound to "updateAll".  There's nothing special about that reference - specifically, nothing "remembers" that the reference came from a property of your "myCounter" object.

You can write a function that takes a function as an argument and returns a new function that's built specifically to run your function with a specific object as the "this" pointer. Lots of libraries have a routine like this; see for example the "functional.js" library and its "bind" function. Here's a real simple version:

```
function bind(funcToCall, desiredThisValue) {
  return function() { funcToCall.apply(desiredThisValue); };
}
```

Now you can write:

```
document.getElementById('myTextField').onkeydown = bind(myCounter.updateAll, myCounter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
function start() {
    //This is the problem
    document.getElementbyId('mytextfield').onkeydown = function() { myCounter.updateAll(); };
    document.getElementbyId('mytextfield').onkeyup = function() { myCounter.updateAll(); };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net Ajax you can use

```
Function.createDelegate(myObject, myFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to do something like this but simpler.
The idea is to have the user click on bolded text and have a text field appear where they can change all the values of a role-playing character. Then when the value is changed, have the text field disappear again replaced by the updated bolded text value.
I can do this already using an annoying text box alert. But I would rather have something similar to this below to replace all that.
I have searched for months and CMS is the closest to answering my question in the simplest way with a full html example. Nobody else on the net could.

So my question is, how do I do this?
I have multiple objects(characters) and need this.elementId to make this work.

I've modified this example but it breaks if I try to add to it.

```
html>
head>
title>Sandbox
/head>
body>
input id="textarea1" size=10 type=text>

script>
function CharCounter(sourceId, statusId)
 {this.sourceId=sourceId;
  this.statusId=statusId;
  this.count=0;
 }
CharCounter.prototype.updateAll=function() 
 {text=document.getElementById(this.sourceId).value 
  document.getElementById(this.statusId).innerHTML=text
 }
CharCounter.prototype.start=function()
 {instance=this 
  document.getElementById(this.sourceId).onkeyup=function ()
   {instance.updateAll()} 
 }
window.onload=function ()
 {myCharCounter=new CharCounter('textarea1', 'status')
  myCharCounter.start()
 }
/script>
/body>
/html>
```

Comment: Thank you EFraim and Ryu! Also, in JQuery 1.4.4, how do I combine -- response=$("getName").val() and response=$(this).val() in the same statement?