# Javascript keyboard event in an object

Tags: javascript, events, object, keyboard

I got my keyboard working in a simple way:

```
rightPressed = false;

onKeyDown = function(pressEvent) {
  if (pressEvent.keyCode == 39) rightPressed = true;
}
onKeyUp = function(pressEvent) {
  if (pressEvent.keyCode == 39) rightPressed = false;
}

$(document).keydown(onKeyDown);
$(document).keyup(onKeyUp);
```

And it worked. Then i tried to put it all in a class:

```
function Tkeyboard(){
this.rightPressed = false;

this.onKeyDown = function(pressEvent) {
  if (pressEvent.keyCode == 39) { this.rightPressed = true; alert("boom!"); }
}
this.onKeyUp = function(pressEvent) {
  if (pressEvent.keyCode == 39) { this.rightPressed = false; }
}

$(document).keydown(this.onKeyDown);
$(document).keyup(this.onKeyUp);
}
```

In initialization I created an object:

```
keys = new Tkeyboard;
```

In main loop i put action:

```
if ( keys.rightPressed ) { rx+=1;}
```

And now it fails. The interesting part of the problem is that alert("boom!") is called, so variable should get modified too...

I would be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run an object's method onEvent in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505624/how-do-i-run-an-objects-method-onevent-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an event handler in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/bind/#event-handlers) (and in DOM events), `this` refers to the element the event is subscribed on (`document` in the sample). Use a [closure](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) if you want to refer to the original object.

```
function Tkeyboard(){
    var self = this;
    this.rightPressed = false;

    this.onKeyDown = function(pressEvent) {
      if (pressEvent.keyCode == 39) { self.rightPressed = true; alert("boom!"); }
    }
    this.onKeyUp = function(pressEvent) {
      if (pressEvent.keyCode == 39) { self.rightPressed = false; }
    }

    $(document).keydown(this.onKeyDown);
    $(document).keyup(this.onKeyUp);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The keydown/up callback loses its original scope when the it is actually run. You'll need to [bind](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/bind) the callback to `this`. In the [Prototype Framework](http://www.prototypejs.org/), you would do this:

```
function Tkeyboard() {
    this.rightPressed = false;

    $(document).keydown(this.onKeyDown.bind(this));
    $(document).keyup(this.onKeyUp.bind(this));
}

Tkeyboard.prototype.onKeyDown = function(pressEvent) {
  if (pressEvent.keyCode == 39) { this.rightPressed = true; alert("boom!"); }
};
Tkeyboard.prototype.onKeyUp = function(pressEvent) {
  if (pressEvent.keyCode == 39) { this.rightPressed = false; }
};
```

It should be similar in [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

If you need an idea of how to build a full fledged keyboard class, check out [the one I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149401/keyboard-alt-modifier-cannot-be-overridden).

Answer (score 1):

`this` is set to the DOM element (in this case `document`) from which the event handler is called. In general, `this` is not bound to the object in javascript:

```
var a = {
    f: function () {}
};
var b = { f: a.f};
var f = a.f;
a.f(); // this === a
b.f(); // this === b
f(); // this === window
```

One commonly used workaround is to bind `this` to a wrapper function:

```
function bind(func, that) {
    return function() {
        func.apply(that, arguments);
    }
}

//...
$(document).keydown(bind(this.onKeyDown, this));
```

Or you could use closures:

```
function Tkeyboard() {
    var that = this;
// use 'that' from here on
```

Answer (score 0):

you can initiate new function it will work

```
    function Tkeyboard() {
    this.rightPressed = false;
    this.onKeyDown = function (pressEvent) {
        if (pressEvent.keyCode == 39) {
            this.rightPressed = true;
            console.log(this.rightPressed )
            alert('boom')
        }
    }
    this.onKeyUp = function (pressEvent) {
        if (pressEvent.keyCode == 39) {
            this.rightPressed = false;
            console.log(this.rightPressed )
        }
    }

    this.events = function(){
        document.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown);
        document.addEventListener('keyup', this.onKeyUp);

    }
}
const keys = new Tkeyboard;
keys.events();
```